# Can't use signInWithEmailAndPassword in flutter app when offline

Tags: firebase-authentication, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-authentication

I'm attempting to use Firebase Auth in a Flutter app that is also using Cloud Firestore. The problem I'm having is what to do when offline.

I journal the username and password and attempt to login using the following code:

```
    _user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: account, password: myPassword).catchError((error) {
  print(error);
});

await _user.getIdToken().catchError((error) {
  // The error source may be that they are not currently connected to the internet
  print(error);
});
final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
```

The problem is that signInWithEmailAndPassword is failing when I'm offline. I need the FirebaseUser object to access Cloud Firestore. I've read about authentication state persistence but this doesn't seem to be available for Flutter.

I know this has to work and I'm just too new to understand how to use Firebase Auth with Cloud Firestore in an offline setting. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to test to see if the user is already authenticated. The Firebase documentation says:

> If your app uses Firebase Authentication, the Firebase Realtime Database client persists the user's authentication token across app restarts. If the auth token expires while your app is offline, the client pauses write operations until your app re-authenticates the user, otherwise the write operations might fail due to security rules.

So I simply check 1st. Here is the code:

```
// If user is already logged in, currentUser will return the authenticated user
// Otherwise, _user will be null.
_user = await _auth.currentUser();
if(_user == null) {
  _user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: account, password: myPassword).catchError((error) {
    print(error);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication cannot possibly work while offline.  It's absolutely required to be able to connect to Firebase backend services in order to validate the user's account and update the user id token that's used to access other Firebase services while online.  Otherwise, the system wouldn't really be secure.

Answer (score 0):

How would you authenticate the user without connect to the Authentication server?
You need an active connection to authenticate the user.
You can store Firebase Cloud Firestore / Realtime database data in the phone (Disk Persistence) but not the Authentication, as this is to prevent abusive access from the local storage.

So one way to handle this is to only show the login dialog when the user's device is [connected to the network](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) and/or [connected to Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state).

Comment: I understand that we can't authenticate without a connection. So, how do we access Cloud Firestore (CF) data that is persisted locally without first authenticating in some way. The only way we could access CF data in an offline setting is if we allow open R/W access WITHOUT authentication. This doesn't make sense. So, there must be some way of persisting the authentication so that we can access CF data. That is the question I'm asking.

Comment: I just copied this from the Firebase doc: If your app uses Firebase Authentication, the Firebase Realtime Database client persists the user's authentication token across app restarts. If the auth token expires while your app is offline, the client pauses write operations until your app re-authenticates the user, otherwise the write operations might fail due to security rules.